# Put a number on both sides

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

Make the following equation correct by putting an exact same number on both sides of the equation. The final equation must be an "equal to" equation only. No "less than or greater than" allowed.

[image: Starting equation initially reads < = V]

Comment: Just to clarify, are we restricted to putting one instance of the number on each side?

Comment: Same number. For example if you put say 8 somewhere on the left hand side, you must put 8 somewhere on the right hand side.

Comment: Would a 'calculation-puzzle' or 'lateral-thinking' tag be appropriate here? (It's not really a traditional 'riddle' type question so I've removed that tag for now...)

Comment: It is not a calculation but some lateral thinking could work

Comment: Now that this has an accepted answer, it looks like it was a "guess what I was thinking" puzzle. The first posted answer is at least as valid as the accepted answer.

Comment: I believe the question should have said to put the exact same ***numeral*** on each side.  Numbers are abstract mathematical objects, distinct from the numerals used to represent them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add

> II, roman numerals for 2, on each side and get the following:
>  [image]
>  1k (prefix for thousand) = M (roman numerals for thousand)

Comment: Terng. Vg vf nyfb ahzore 11

Comment: @RogerA Yes. rot13 (V whfg gubhtug gung jbhyq or zber svggvat fvapr gurer ner ab "ung" (nf gurer vf va gur ahzore 1) ba x naq Z)

Answer (score 11):

An unconventional solution:

> Add V (5) to both sides like this: 
>  **>**< = v 
> ______**^** 
>  i.e. X = X in Roman numerals.

Comment: "Gjb ynml i'f "

Comment: To me this feels like a more intuitive answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

Left hand side is a bit tilted:

> [image]